# Made a mistake on my CV regarding length of employment

Tags: job-offer, employment, employment-gaps

I was offered a job verbally and was advised that background checks would be carried out. I have been contacted by a third party company asking about the dates of employment as I advised on my CV that I was employed up until September when in fact I left my previous job in June and was unemployed for 3 months which I stated on the questionnaire they sent to me. I corrected them and advised them of the correct information.

Will this affect my job chances badly?

Answer (score 6):

> Will this affect my job chances badly?

Most likely, this will **not** have any impact.  You were **accurate** with the information in the questionnaire, but had a *discrepancy* on the CV.  A minor mistake like this would not stop me from hiring you as this was an obvious mistake versus an attempt to cover up the gap.

Be sure to correct your CV so going forward its 100% accurate.

Comment: Yes. You have been honest in pointing out that you made a mistake and it's unlikely your work history matters too much as it's likely you've been offered a job based on your skills / aptitude.